# How to add an image to array using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add an image to an array. When I use Node it works, but when I use the same way to add images it does not appear when I run it. Here is my code:

```
public class PlatForm extends Application {
    List<ImageView> platFormList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Pane layout;
    private Scene scene;
    private AnimationTimer platFormTimer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        layout = new Pane();
        scene = new Scene(layout,800,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        platFormTimer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                uploadPlatForm();
            }
        };
        platFormTimer.start();
    }

    public void uploadPlatForm(){
        for(ImageView platform : platFormList)
            platform.setTranslateX(platform.getTranslateX() + Math.random() * 10);
        if (Math.random() < 0.075) {
            platFormList.add(newPlatForm());
        }
    }

    private ImageView newPlatForm(){
        ImageView platFormImg =
            new ImageView(
                new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/platform.png")
            )
        );
        layout.getChildren().add(platFormImg);
        platFormImg.setTranslateY((int)(Math.random() * 14) * 40);
        return platFormImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks basically correct. Are you sure the image is in the expected location (should be an `image` folder in the root of the classpath, and a `platform.png` file in it)? (If you just try to display a single image, e.g. replace `platformTimer.start()` with `newPlatForm()`, does it show an image?) Slightly off-topic: you don't need to load a new `Image` every time; you can just load one image and use the same one for all the `ImageView`s.

Comment: I tested and this worked fine for me, so I think your image path must be wrong.

Comment: sorry, there was fail in path. it appears now. but regarding what did you say about using one image. I want to generate a platform in different position for my jumping game. I do not want to set position for every platform, I want to make a code that generate a particular numbers of platforms in different positions. is there another easy way than using AnimationTimer ? @James_D

Comment: how I can use the same one for all the ImageViews? @James_D

Comment: Just create a single image `private Image image = new Image("/image/platform.png");` and then in the `newPlatForm()` method just do `ImageView platFormImg = new ImageView(image);`.